# Socket.io emits duplicate data after browser refresh

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

I have a page that has a button. When the button is clicked, it gets data through socket.io. However, each time I reload the page, socket.io will send back one extra copy of data from the previous data set. So my data would look good first time the page load (example: abcd). Then reload the page will get back 2n data (abcdabcd), reload the page again I get 3n data (abcdabcdabcd) etc.

How do I avoid duplicated data send back to the client when page reload? Here is my code.

Server Side:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){

        // some code...

    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){

        var socketFn = function(data){
            socket.emit("trends", {
                trends: JSON.parse(redisData)
            });
        };

        socket.on("action", socketFn);

        socket.on("disconnect", function(){
            socket.removeListener("action", socketFn); // this doesn't work
        });

    });
    res.render('test');

});
```

Client Side:

```
    var socketOpts = {
    "sync disconnect on unload" : true
};
var socket = io.connect("", socketOpts);

socket.on("trends", function(data){
    // data received from the node server, so do something with it
});


function action(){
    socket.emit("action", {phrase: "some dummy data"});
    return false;
}

// already checked client side doesn't fire multiple click event
$("button#click").off("click").on("click", action);
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you listen to connection as many times as client hits the page.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
//when client opens the page 

    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    //start listening to new connection
    ...
```

It is considered a bad idea to initialize connection eventlisteners from within your routes. It should be done only once globally. Here each time your client accesses the page it will listen to the events as many times page is accessed.

Comment: What if I want to initialize connection event listeners within my routes? What if I have 10 pages and only on 1 I want to implement socket.io.

Comment: @miksii Still a bad idea. You create multiple connection handlers - as many times as the page is hit. Page hits will kill your socket.io server. If you have a separate question create a new one. My answer solves OP's particular problem.

Comment: I am wondering whether I should create a new topic or not. In my case I have /dashboard route that renders dashboard.jade page. Within that page I have simple chat app using socket.io and mongodb. I've noticed that if I set my programming logic for sockets inside my /dashboard routes the data is being duplicated each time I refresh page. For example; if I sent "abc" it will sent "abc", than if I refresh my page and sent "abc" it will sent "abc", "abc". Any suggestion for that? ps. I can create a new question and make your suggestion as an answer if you will. Thanks.

Comment: @miksiii Give it a test by removing the part inside the route. It is a common pitfall, most likely it is not what people want but don't know how to add it. What you add inside connection sticks forever unless you remove it explicitly. You probably want to to make it connect to server after initial connection is established already.

Comment: I've opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350928/nodejs-socket-io-emit-duplicate-data-within-route
Thanks.